# Numeric comparison creating a small file

Tags: powershell

If I try this in powershell against an empty directory i.e. the directory at `$ad` has no items in it:

```
$ad = "C:/Stats/Scripts_ps1/experiment";
$items = get-childitem($ad);
if($items.count>0){write-host "hello"};
```

It seems to run ok but when I look in directory there is a tiny file titled `0`!

I assume this is wrong `if($items.count>0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, `>` is a [stream redirection operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx).

To perform [a comparison](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx), use `-gt` (*greater than*):

```
if($items.Count -gt 0){ # there is more than zero items }
```

---

Similarly, other comparison operators follow a similar pattern:

```
PowerShell  C#  Meaning
----------  --  -----------------
       -eq  ==  Equals
       -ne  !=  Not equals
       -gt   >  Greater than
       -lt   <  Less than
       -ge  >=  Greater or equals
       -le  <=  Less or equals
```

Comment: lol ... I'm generally enjoying trying to learn a little ps ...it's fun...this error of min makes me laugh. This has got it `help("about_comparison_operators")`

Comment: @whytheq Don't put `()` around your arguments, you're gonna get burnt

Comment: In PowerShell, positional parameter arguments are separated by *spaces*, not commas, so the instant you need to supply more than one argument to a cmdlet and do `Get-ChildItem ($path,$filter,$recurse)`, all three arguments will be treated as one big array instead of separate arguments. Not to mention the fact that you make your code slight unreadable to anyone familiar with the proper syntax